# How to use Scotty's ActionT monad like a Maybe monad, with an early http response returned for errors?

Tags: haskell, scotty

I would like to be able to return custom error pages and statuses to the user, and end computation in the [ActionT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.11.5/docs/Web-Scotty-Internal-Types.html#t:ActionT) monad when such an error occurs. My understanding is that this is a bit like a `Maybe` monad, where computation ends when the first `Nothing` is encountered, but with a final error message emitted (to the user via HTTP).

I have a code snippet that looks like this:

```
  liftIO $ scotty (config & port & fromEnum) $
    get "/cow/:mark" $ do
      qParams :: DM.Map LTxt.Text LTxt.Text <- DM.fromList <$> params
      markTxt <- param "mark"
      let intervalTxtMay = DM.lookup "interval" qParams
      let cowMarkMaybe = TR.readMaybe $ Txt.unpack markTxt
      cowMark <- case cowMarkMaybe of
        Nothing -> do
          status status404
          textLazy $ "Couldn't parse cow mark " ++  markTxt ++ " as integer."
          finish
        Just cmVal-> pure $ CowMark cmVal
      liftIO $ logLogIt Debug lgr ["***** Made it past cowMark ******"]
      ...
```

There are at least two problems with the code: `finish` doesn't seem to do anything particularly useful here, i.e., computation continues and I still see the message `***** Made it past cowMark ******` in my logs each time load a page that would normally trigger the 404.
The second problem is that the 404 error is not enacted, I get a 200 response even when it should be a 404.

Is there a way to achieve the desired behavior in Scotty?

Comment: At the moment, I am considering wrapping ActionT in ExceptT with a custom error type that can be transformed into a response.

Comment: I bet it doesn't print "Couldn't parse cow mark " either. If it does, try printing cowMark in ... in a case where it shouldn't have a value and see what happens.

Comment: @Gurkenglas you are correct, it doesn't print that either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both problems stem from the `Nothing` case never being entered, because the `TR.readMaybe` always succeeds. Print `markTxt` and `cowMarkMaybe` in a case where the latter should be `Nothing`.

Comment: Ah yes, this was a logic issue for me - I was using a query that parsed correctly, but was not in the database, and somehow while debugging this I had equated to two in my mind, forgetting that there was no check for whether or not it was in the database.